# Is the standard isomorphism $L(F^n,F^n)\to F^{n\times n}$ a natural transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, natural-transformations

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. I was wondering if the algebra isomorphism $$\Phi\colon L(F^n,F^n)\to F^{n\times n}$$ defined by
$$A(x)=\Phi(A)\cdot x\quad\forall x\in F^n$$
is in some sense a "natural transformation", e.g. as defined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation).

Comment: In the title you have $F^n$, in the body you have $V$ and do not specify a "natural" basis?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, that was a mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. "V" has been replaced by "F^n".

Comment: intuitively: it cannot be natural because you need to specify a basis to write every linear map as a matrix

Comment: $L$ is the space of linear transformations between the two?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, exactly.

Comment: So your functor is $G(F^n)=L(F^n,F^n),$ but if $f:F^n\to F^m,$ what is $G(f)?$ Natural transformations need a functor.

Comment: @Masacroso I understand that every basis of $F^n$ defines an isomorphism between matrices and linear maps, but I have the feeling that the isomorphism defined by the standard basis is somehow "special". I am wondering if there is more to the story.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option, but first some notation:

1. If $\textsf{C}$ and $\textsf{D}$ are categories, and $F : \textsf{C} \to \textsf{D}$ is a functor, then $F^{\rm op} : \textsf{C}^{\rm op} \to \textsf{D}^{\rm op}$ denotes the functor defined on objects and morphisms as same as $F$.
2. If $F_1: \textsf{C}_1 \to \textsf{D}_1$ and $F_2 : \textsf{C}_2 \to \textsf{D}_2$ are arbitrary functors, then $$F_1 \times F_2 : \textsf{C}_1 \times \textsf{C}_2 \to \textsf{D}_1 \times \textsf{D}_2$$ denotes the functor defined by $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto (F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2))$ (for objects and morphisms).
3. For a locally small category $\textsf{C}$ we have the two-sided represented functor $\operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{C} : \textsf{C}^{\rm op} \times \textsf{C} \to \textsf{Set}$ which sends a pair of objects $(x,y)$ in $\textsf{C}$ to the set $\operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{C}(x,y)$.

Now note that if $\textsf{C}$ and $\textsf{D}$ are locally small, every functor $F : \textsf{C} \to \textsf{D}$ induces a natural transformation $F^\flat : \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{C} \to \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{D} \circ \,(F^{\rm op} \times F)$ whose component at $(x,y)$ is the function $$\operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{C}(x,y) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{D}(F(x),F(y))$$ which sends $f : x \to y$ to $F(f) : F(x) \to F(y)$.

Finally, if $k$ is a field, in the special case in which

- $\textsf{C}$ is the category $\textsf{Mat}_k$ whose objects are the natural numbers $0,1,2,\dots$ and morphisms $n \to m$ are $m \times n$ matrices with entries in $k$,
- $\textsf{D}$ is the category $k\textsf{-Vect}$ whose objects are $k$-vector spaces and morphisms are linear maps, and
- $F$ is the functor $k^{(\_)} : \textsf{Mat}_k \to k\textsf{-Vect}$ which takes $n$ to $k^n$ and a matrix $A$ to the linear map $A\_$ (left-multiplication by $A$);

then we see that $F^\flat$ is a natural transformation whose component at $(n,m)$ is the function $$k^{m \times n} = \operatorname{Hom}_{\textsf{Mat}_k}(n,m) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{k\textsf{-Vect}}(k^n,k^m) = L(k^n,k^m)$$ given by $A \mapsto A\_$, so that the component at $(n,n)$ is the inverse of your map $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your beginner friendly answer! In the part where you explain $F^\flat$, the code is not processed the way you intended.

Comment: @Filippo Oh, I don't see any error in the code processing. But let me edit some stuffs.

Comment: Thank you - I have very slow internet right now and strange things happen when I load the site. To me it still looks like there is an error - I will check your answer as soon as I have Wifi and let you know.

Comment: I now have Wifi and everything looks good :) When I asked the question, I only knew natural transformations from the context of tensor products, tangent spaces and other stuff defined by some universal property. In particular, I have no knowledge of category theory and I'll need to learn the basics to properly understand the answer. I currently have to prepare the presentation of my Bachelor thesis, but I hope I'll find time soon. In the meantime, do you have any recommendation for where to start?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems in producing such natural transformation. First is basis for $F^n$. Second is how the domain and codomain of the linear map can be ensured to contain same field of scalars. But you can assume this and consider $A_{ij} = L(B_i)_j$, where $L : F^n \rightarrow F^m$ and $A : F^{n \times m}$. The intermediate vector $B_i$ is a inverse image of L for projection $A_i$ of a matrix $A$ to its i'th row vector, $B_i \in L^{-1}(A_i)$. Note using this projection in defining scalars of the matrix has serious self-reference problem, but assuming in abstract that the row vectors $B_i$ exist, will require existence of basis sufficient that it's possible to apply L to the row vector. It's possible to choose the formal expression for representation of vectors $B_i = \sum_{j \in [1,n]}{B_{ij}x_j}$ where $x_j$ are the basis elements and compute using the free vector space.

The natural transformation is a map taking $L$ to $A$, with $F$ (the field of scalars) kept abstract by both the functor and natural transformation. In detail
$α : L(-^n,-^m) \rightarrow (-^{n \times m}) : Fld \rightarrow Set$, defined by $α_F(L : L(F^n,F^m))_{ij}=L(B_i)_j$.
But as the above shows, the natural transformation would have to invent $B_i$ from thin air, only using $F$ and $L$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - why do you consider "basis for $F^n$" a problem?

Comment: It's not quite. Problem is that I'm using projection of the matrix that is being defined, trying to keep the scalars as abstract. The natural transformation doesn't quite need definition of the scalars, but has to be careful that the circularity doesn't mean the construction doesn't work. Thus I end up with using formal expressions for vectors rather than actual scalars.

Comment: There is another question regarding basis of $F^n$. It might be possible to use, say, $F^2$ as field of scalars for $F^{2m}$, which is different than using $F$ as scalars. Avoiding such vector spaces needs choice of what scalars are, and this choice is crucial when we want to abstract out scalars.